# Replace value of a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My question is how to replace the value of a cell based on its header.

Here's my sample data. I want to replace all the "x" values with the date in the columns header.

[image: sample data raw]

The output should be like this:

[image: sample data output]

I don't know how to create a macro for this. I wonder if I can add a macro in the sheet itself so that it will automatically run without clicking any button every time a value is changed.

Comment: You would need a macro to do this.  Have you tried recording one while you did it manually to at least get a code starting point?  Keep in mind that the site isn't intended as a free coding service, but people will help you solve specific problems you encounter trying to do it yourself.  You will need to show your work and what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to replace all the "x" values with the date in the columns header.

```
Sub MyReplace()
Dim OneCell As Range
For Each OneCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If OneCell.Column > 1 And OneCell.Row > 1 Then
        If OneCell.Value = "x" Then
            OneCell.Value = OneCell.EntireColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

> automatically run without clicking any button every time a value is changed.

```
Dim flag As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim OneCell As Range
If flag Then Exit Sub
flag = True
For Each OneCell In Target
    If OneCell.Column > 1 And OneCell.Row > 1 Then
        If OneCell.Value = "x" Then
            OneCell.Value = OneCell.EntireColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
Next
flag = False
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir :) it worked well. I just need to understand the code for me to understand and learn the macro well :)

Comment: @Cleo Set breakpoint on the first operator in a procedire which allows BP setting. Execute it (by F5 for the first or by inserting 'x' into some cell for second). Then trace the code step-by-step (F8). View variables values in Locals window and expressions (like `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address`, `OneCell.Address`, etc.) values in Watch window, try to predict how will they be changed by the next operator, then step and compare your prediction with real values change.